# Update json file in server using vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm getting started with vuejs and I was wondering if we can update data of a file in the server using vuejs? I know we can fetch but can we update? I tried searching all over but I don't seem to find anything related.

Comment: Can you be more specific? as I see serverside means any API/ serverside programming language that you are using along with Vuejs? Try using Nodejs it easy.

Comment: I have not given a thought to it yet but I just need to update json file in server. What is the best way to do it? apart from using nodejs or angular?

Comment: Are you actually talking about how to use the `fetch` API to do update?

Comment: No i know we can fetch. btw its not api but a static file containing data in json format. i want to update it from frontend like edit and save options

Comment: i dont think you can update a json file stored on your server using vuejs. you have to use any server side technology like node, php, java etc. to first get the data from the frontend using API and then update the json file. However, i recommend you to use node for this.